# Flutter Android app not running setting compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to SDK 31

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to execute a Flutter project on a new Android device.

Flutter version is 1.22.4.

Here you have the app/build.gradle file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "red.faro.flutter_capenergy"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

                }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
}
```

And here you have AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="red.faro.flutter_capenergy">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="Capenergy"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/iconpushapp" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="fcm_default_channel"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

When launching the app on a new Android device (SDK 31), the debugger is showing the following error message:

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1

Performing Streamed Install


adb: failed to install /Users/modestovascofornas/Desarrollo/2022-G2-CAPENERGY-FLUTTER-PROFESIONAL/FLUTTER/flutter_capenergy/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl644805330.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #80): io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86
```

Setting compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 30 do launch the app as it should.

Executing the app on older devices makes no issue at all.

The only issue is launching the app  with compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion set to 31 on Android devices > SDK 30

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN the AndroidManifest.xml, every activity tag must have the `android:exported="true"` set.

Update:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

to

```
<activity
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Comment: let me try your proposal

Comment: same error, may be another issue due to the Flutter version (1.22.4)

Comment: i am running v2.10.3 and it resolved my issue

Comment: try setting minSdkVersion 21\

Comment: let me try with minSdkVersion 21

Comment: same error, adb: failed to install /Users/modestovascofornas/Desarrollo/2022-G2-CAPENERGY-FLUTTER-PROFESIONAL/FLUTTER/flutter_capenergy/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl109867839.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #81): io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64.

Comment: can you add root level build.grade?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245797/discussion-between-mvasco-and-suzan).